# Password for loop

Tags: c#

This is for an intro to programming class. Is there a way to throw an error and exit the console after the 4th failed attempt at verifying the username and password? Currently the program just starts over.

```
bool varIsValid = true;
int loginAttempts = 4;
string username = null;
string password = null;

while (varIsValid)
{
    try
    {
        //Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("\n Welcome to the updated Final Project Program! \n" +
                          "--------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        for (int i = 0; i < loginAttempts; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n Please enter your username: \n");
            username = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("\n Please enter your password \n");
            password = Console.ReadLine();

            if (username == "username" && password == "password!%")
            {
                Class1.Cis();
            }
            else if (username == "altusername" && password == "password")
            {
                Class1.Other();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please try a different username or password.");
            }
        } 
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error! Something went wrong with the program.");
    }
}
```

Comment: `the program is supposed to exit. If I do an Environment.Exit(0); It just exits the program.` What's the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm a bad at explaining. It exits on the first invalid password. It's supposed to exit on the forth. Also I am supposed to give an invalid message.

Comment: @Jade Create a counter that keeps track of the number of invalid passwords.

Comment: Side note, you don't need to separate the newlines from the rest of the string. It makes it difficult to read. `"\n Please enter your username:\n"` is cleaner and easier to follow imo

Comment: Where is the `Environment.Exit(0)` in your code? You really should provide us the full code (a [mcve]) that we can run.

Comment: Also, since you're learning try not to fall in to the bad habit of doing `catch (Exception e)` - it's a bad habit and an anti-pattern. It'll make your code harder to debug, not easier. You should only ever catch specific exceptions that you can meaningfully handle.

Comment: Thanks for the info. We just use Execption e in our intro class. Literally everything I use is stuff that my teacher has taught us. I had Environment.Exit(0) after the Console.WriteLine in the last part else.

Comment: What type of Exception would you suggest for this code, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @Jade, The point of exceptions is that there are two different places: the one where the exception happened (and where you usually don't know what to do with it) and the one where you finally know what to do with it (which is usually in a very different part of a code). Therefore, you're supposed to catch exceptions where you know what to do with them. Since in your case you don't know what to do with them, it's a wrong place to catch it. The best option here is to simply allow the program to fail with exception, whatever is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to stop the loop, use **break;** instead of **Environment.Exit(0);**

Answer (score 1):

Use `break`, reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break)

The following example shows how to use it, example from link above:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    if (i == 5)
    {
        break;   // this line breaks the for loop
    }
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put my for loop in its own class and just referenced it on the main program. Then I was able to exit the program with a message.